# JBoss server 7.1 not starting in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss7.x, eclipse-luna

I have Eclipse Luna 4.4.1, and JBoss Server 7.1. The problem is when I start the Server, it never starts and after a long time it says Time Out Error. "JBoss is unable to start within 450 seconds".

How to resolve this issue?

The Console shows the following output and just hangs here for much time:

```
12:47:54,100 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
12:47:54,438 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
12:47:54,552 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

The Server never starts. I have changed the time settings but it never helps.

Comment: @Juru Can you please suggests some help

Comment: can you paste the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes, JBoss AS 7.1 will not start with JDK 1.8. Here it is, right from JBoss... https://developer.jboss.org/thread/223739?start=0&tstart=0. You think they would have fixed it by now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I solved that issue, I was using JDK version 1.8 and JBOSS 7.1, The JBOSS server always stuck on "Starting Brontes".... I have tried changing the server startup time, and settings but nothing helped.

I then unistalled JDK 1.8, and installed JDK 1.7, and this solves my issue. JBOSS 7.1 works with JDK 1.7.. :)

And one thing more,  JDK 1.8 can work with JBOSS WildFly 8...

Answer (score 3):

Compare the Java Build Path properties in your projects, maybe you mixed up the JDK versions.
I faced the same problem..using different java runtime environments in server an project configuration seems not to be the best way for starting the JBoss :)

Answer (score 2):

If someone hit this problem in the future...

JBoss 7.1 need Runtime JRE 1.7. Edit this under Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments > JBoss 7.1 > edit > Runtime JRE (Change to 7.1)

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the timeout associated with server starting time as part of the server settings in Eclipse. You might also want to check if you need all the modules that JBOSS starts up as part of the startup process. 6 minutes is a long time in a development environment. Do you have lot of apps being deployed? Would you  need all of them for a development environment?

Comment: I have tried increasing the time, but it is not helping. I have set the time out to 500 sec..

Comment: What is the time that it takes for JBOSS to start outside of Eclipse? You might want to finetune on the basis of that. Of course, please do verify if you need all of those apps that are present.

Comment: May be the problem is with the port settings, I dont kno how to set the Jboss and Eclipse ports. JBoss is using 8080 Web port.

Comment: It wouldn't be due to port settings. How much time does it take for JBOSS to start independently - not within Eclipse? You know, when you run it as standalone?

Comment: Same on command propmpt, JBoss says starting are never starts. Please tell me how can i lessens the number of apps , i am a newbie

Comment: I have no app. I am just trying to configure the environment to start learning, how to develop a webpage

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know that I can't run JBoss As 7.1 on JDK 1.8 and I had the same problem as Madhya Rehman. I've checked if jdk in project properties and jboss runtime is the same, then I set checkbox in project properties/project facets/ runtimes page/ jboss 7.1 runtime ant it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse:

- Double click on server
- Go to General information
- Change Run environment to Java 1.8

And it will work fine... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem and changing the java version helped me.

Comment: Maybe include more specifics, such as what version you changed it to, and how you changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to start the Jboss bundled with liferay server on jboss as 7.1.I also had similar issue. I changed jre from 1.8 version  to 1.7 that solved my issue and server started successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Another posible fix is to change the hostname, from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' in eclipse jboss server configuration pane, in the 'General Information' section